# "Sleep" not an option for "Lid close action" on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8

When you go to power options in the control panel for Windows 8, under power buttons and lid >> lid close action >> on battery/plugged in, you should be able to choose

a. Do nothing
b. Sleep
c. Hibernate
d. Shut down

However, sleep is not an option for me ever since I updated to Windows 8.1. Screenshot:

[image]

The update also screwed up a lot of stuff. Very annoying. The computer is an Asus Zenbook. Any suggestions?

Thanks a bunch!

(if this is the wrong stackexchange forum, I apologize)

Comment: Weird, I see the option in Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > System Settings > Power button and lid settings. I have Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: I have same problem too, if you solved your problem please add the resolution

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer,
When `Hyper-V` is enabled the sleep option won't show up.
To disable `Hyper-V` follow these instructions

1. Open Windows Features.
2. Expand the Hyper-V sub-section

[image]

3. To Disable Hyper-V

   Uncheck Hyper-V, click/tap on OK, and go to step 4 below.
4. Restart the computer when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the 'Power Options' icon in taskbar. Then click 'More power options'.

A new windows will open. On the left side panel click on 'What closing the lid does'. [image]

Well you may have understood. Chose your desired option!

Comment: I have same problem and still there is no sleep option in the combo boxes in your screen shot! neither down in this form as checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can try fiddling with powercfg via cmd, there are a lot of knobs that can be turned.

If you cannot fix it, the zenbook I tried has a preload partition - just reinstall from this, it doesn't take too long. It doesn't seem to do snapshots of your system like some Acer laptops do, so you would want to back up your data.